# poor performance of paintComponent() on JPanel

Tags: java, performance, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a performance issue with the code I post here.
I am a JAVA newbie and I am trying to repaint Images on a JPanel which is then displayed on a JFrame. After a lot of trial and error the code finally works. The problem is that the performance of it is very low. The images that are being repainted seem to lag. Also when I move the JFrame on my screen it lags. I use Eclipse on OS Linux Mint. I am not sure whether that is the problem or the code.
I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Simon

Main Class:

```
package pack1;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7460454277320732933L;
public static BufferedImage image;
public static int y = 0;
public static BufferedImage image2;
public static int y2 = -600;

public Main() {

    try {
     image = ImageIO.read(new File("spazio/stelle.png"));
     image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("spazio/stelle.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Quadro non esiste");
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.drawImage(image, 0, y, 800,600,null);
g2.drawImage(image2, 0, y2,800,600,null);
repaint();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Spazio");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Main panel = new Main();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
    f.add(panel);
    f.setSize(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());
    f.setVisible(true);
    new Background();
    }

}
```

Class Background:

```
package pack1;

import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;

public class Background {
 Timer back;
    public Background(){
    back = new Timer();
    back.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask (){

        @Override
 public void run(){
     if (Main.y<600) {
         Main.y+= 2;
     }
     if (Main.y2<600) {
         Main.y2+=2;
     }
     else if (Main.y>=600) Main.y = 0;
     else if (Main.y2>=600) Main.y2=-595; 
 }},0,80);





    }

}
```

Comment: Do not, ever, call, directly or indirectly, `repaint` within your `paintComponent` method.  This is just going to trigger a new repaint event continuously until it consumes all your thread cycles, generates a singularity and sucks us all into oblivion ... or something like that.  Swing is also not thread safe, making the use of `java.util.Timer` is inaaprioate and you should use a Swing `Timer` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot! So suppose that I would stick to the util Timer, where would I put the repaint method? Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't `repaint`, the problem is the fact that you are updating one or more properties that the UI depends on in order to render it's state, this leads you to the possibility of dirty reads and other threading issues.  You "should" use `EventQueue.invokeLater` to push the update onto the EDT, which is done automatically by Swing `Timer` or use a `SwingWorker` which can also do this for for you

Answer (score 0):

MadProgrammer is correct in his comment.  Your first change should be this.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, y, 800, 600, null);
    g2.drawImage(image2, 0, y2, 800, 600, null);
}
```

**Always** call super paintComponent and **never** repaint inside of the paint component method.